# Replace onclick

Tags: javascript

i want when click on phone code text it show the second hint span hint2 and when click on phone number text its  show the first hint span is that possible to do with JavaScript only????

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Javascript Change Div InnerHTM</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="pasha_css/hint.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="pasha_js/hint.js"></script>
    <link href="pasha_css/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="form-item7" class="form-profile">
    <label class="form-phone">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text"  name="Phone_code" value="03" class="form-text phonecode " onclick="this.value=''" onselect="this.value=''"></input>
    <input type="text"  name="phone" value="4567890"
        class="form-text phone" onclick="this.value='';" onselect="this.value=''"></input>
    <span id="hint1" class="hint">Use Text only please!
    <span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
    <span id="hint2" class="hint">enter code!
    <span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use jquery, its javascript only. :P

Answer (score 1):

If the hint `span` elements are hidden by default (using `display:none`) you can show them with `document.getElementById('hintId').style.display = "inline"`.

You probably want to do this in the `onfocus` event of the text fields, otherwise it won't be fired when someone navigates to that field with their keyboard (e.g. using the tab key).

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cPLfd/) for an example.